# Compare and delete duplicate from the dataframe columns with strings and numbers

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to compare the data with two columns and delete the part of identical.
For example, I have data like this:

```
 brand                       model
Coolpad                Coolpad 9190_T00
```

i want to make it like this

```
 brand                   model
Coolpad                9190_T00
```

Also for the data looks like this

```
 brand                       model
vivo Y27           vivo Y27.msm8916_32.msm8916_32
```

what should i do to make it looks like this

```
 brand                       model
vivo Y27                  msm8916_32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can replace the string by applying a `lambda x:` function where `x` is the dataframe and passing `axis=1` to specify column-wise in order to replace one columns values with `''` based off the values of another column.
2. You can then use `.str.extract()` to get rid of all non-alphanumeric characters at the beginning of the string with `\W+` and keep all characters after beginning with the capture group being all alphanumeric characters and everything after with `(\w+.*)`. Everything within`()` will be kept and everything outside will be excluded. The `\w+` at the beginning of `(\w+.*)` might be unnecessary as \W and \w are mutually exclusive, but I wanted to be explicit. You could probably get away with `(.*)`

---

```
In[1]:
           brand                             model
0       vivo Y27    vivo Y27.msm8916_32.msm8916_32
1        Coolpad                  Coolpad 9190_T00
```

---

```
df['model'] = (df.apply(lambda x: x['model'].replace(x['brand'], ''), axis=1)
                 .str.extract('^\W+(\w+.*)')) # or .str.extract('^\W+(.*)'))
df
Out[1]: 
      brand                  model
0  vivo Y27  msm8916_32.msm8916_32
1   Coolpad               9190_T00
```